# Restored 2 day old Microsoft Exchange - lost one month of entries

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a strange situation. On the weekend our Exchange 2010 system got fried, so I pulled out the backup from Friday 12/12/2014 and restored it.

Now when our users reconnect to their mailboxes, whether via Outlook or their phones, they don't see *anything* after 18/11/2014. I watched the content disappear with my own eyes. One moment it was there, the next, bam - gone. Almost a month of data is gone from their devices. Emails, appointments, etc. Everyone's outlook is running in Cached mode - I have no idea what the devices themselves do (some are iPhones, some are Android).

However: If I log into the web interface, everything is intact. I can see entries right up to when the backup was taken.

What's going on? Will the users Outlooks eventually sort themselves out? *New* content (inbound emails) are appearing correctly in the mailbox.

Right now I've just advised our users to get onto their webmail.

Comment: Did you check if it is just the partnership which is fried (e.g. by removing the ActiveSync mailbox configuration settings from the device and re-adding the Exchange account after that)?

Comment: @the-wabbit I haven't tried that yet. I was planning on doing it to one of our users smaller mailboxes soon.

Comment: Just created a new mail profile and connected it. It's taken 25 minutes so far and content is ever so slowly dribbling in. Looks like it might be ok.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you disable Cached Mode for a single client, delete the OST file and then re-enable Cached Mode (or simply delete the OST file) and see what happens, but it looks like your profile recreation is leading you in the same direction.

Comment: Maybe a log error, maybe a mismatch between the db and log as you restored. I know error in the log can prevent a restore to mount, not your case, but maybe worth running a backup to commit all the log if the log folder got old items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patience is a virtue. It took a very long time, but eventually all the items that went missing re-appeared. I suspect that a part of the reason it took so long was because the way Veeam Backup and Recovery works, is you can boot the VM directly off your disk-based backup storage, and then you can do a storage migration off the backup device to your proper storage. This means that you can do a restore of your VM almost instantly.

However, during this stage, depending on your backup hardware, the server can be excruciatingly slow - especially during the storage migration. That doesn't explain why they went away, but it explains why they took so long to come back.